# I set the heroku node.js buildpack, but the prompt still says push rejected coz failed to detect set

Tags: node.js, heroku

I want to deploy a node.js application onto the heroku through github, and I followed the instructions on heroku. but I stuck on the issue which says the push rejected because of the buildpacks are not set,however I did set the nodejs buildpack, I am a noob, I don't know what the problem it is.someone says package.json should contain engine:node version, is that the reason? because I have put the front-end folder and back-end folder separately. so what should the folder structure looks like?

[heroku cli capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUTMR.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` file in the root of your project?

Comment: no, because I separate the front end folder(views js css) and the back-end server(express server), so the package.json file is in back-end server folder, is it necessary to put package.json at root? then where should I put the front-end server files. Cheers

Comment: The root needs a `package.json` file for the buildpack's detect script. It sounds like you're trying to run two distinct applications here which is not supported by dynos. If you have two applications they should be independent projects and deployed separately.

Comment: Thank you for response, I will deploy each by each.